# Why doesn't CSS selector "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 + p" work, and what is an alternative?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a set of CSS selectors that indent paragraphs after certain elements.

I already have `p + p` working fine, but this misses out paragraphs after headers. Trying `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 + p` does not have the desired results -- the header gets indented rather than the paragraph.

Clearly I can fix this by having a separate selector for each level of header (`h1 + p; h2 + p; etc`) but I was wondering if anyone knew a more elegant solution, preferably one selector.

Comment: use `:-webkit-any(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) + p/:-moz-any(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) + p` . Or simply `:not(p) + p`

Comment: selector1 + selector2 means apply style on selector1 where there is an adjacent selector2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you need is the following group of selectors:

```
h1+p, h2+p, h3+p, h4+p, h5+p, h6+p
```

The syntax requires that you add "+p" after each header tag.

In your current selector, the CSS is applied to headers h1-h5 and h6+p.

This may not look elegant, but it is precisely what you need.

Comment: Thanks very much, not sure how I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 2):

**Why doesn't it work?**

`h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 + p` will select all the h6 elements and apply styling to the paragraph element adjacent/sibling to it.

**Alternative:**

If the heading items and paragraph items are the only child elements inside the parent element. Use `:not(p)` for all the elements which excludes `p`

```css
.container *:not(p) + p {
  color: white;
  background: #FF6868;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test h1</h1>
  <p>Test</p>
  <h2>Test h2</h2>
  <p>Test</p>
  <h3>Test h3</h3>
  <p>Test</p>
  <h4>Test h4</h4>
  <p>Test</p>
  <h5>Test h5</h5>
  <p>Test</p>
  <h6>Test h6</h6>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```